# Instance of Arbitrary Haskell

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I need to make an instance of arbitrary on my Haskell program, I'm creating a deck of cards (which is of type deck), and deck is a list of Cards, in order to make a new deck the program uses a mkStdGen and a number to prompt a seed, in order to randomize the new deck.

This deck needs to have an instance of arbitrary to pass the QuickTest property tests.

Here's some code

```
 data Carta = C (Valor,Naipe) deriving (Eq,Ord)

 instance Show Carta where
 show (C (v,n)) =show v ++ show n

 data Baralho = B [Carta] 

  instance Show Baralho where
  show (B []) = ""
  show (B [c]) = show c
  show (B (c:cs)) = show c ++ "," ++ show (B cs)

  type Mao = [Carta]

  baralho40 :: Baralho

  baralho40 = B [C (x,y)|y<-[Paus .. Espadas],x<-[As .. Rei]]

  baralhar :: StdGen -> Baralho -> Baralho

  baralhar g (B baralho) = B $ map snd $ sort $ zip (randomRs (1,(length       baralho)^3) g) baralho
```

Comment: Nice deck of cards... what is your question?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i need to instance it to arbitrary in order to be able to use Test.QuickCheck, but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic instance for `Carta` could be:

```
instance Arbitrary Carta where
  arbitrary = Carta <$> vn
    where
      vn = (,) <$> v <*> n
      v  = elements [Paus .. Espadas]
      n  = elements [As .. Rei]
```

The `elements` function from module `Test.QuickCheck` takes a list of values and returns a generator for those values (i.e. something to select one of those values at random):

```
elements :: [a] -> Gen a
```

The instance above uses this to independently generate a random `Valor` and a random `Naipe` for a card. Those to values are then combined to a tuple (`vn` is a generator for a tuple, type `Gen (Valor,Naipe)`). After that wrap this to a generator for the `Carta` itself.

To generate a random deck of cards (where you don't want to have duplicates), have a look at the function:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> Gen [a]
```

in `Test.QuickCheck`. It generates random permutations of a list of items. It will also be helpful to make `Carta`, `Valor` and `Naipe` elements of `Enum`.